# Adding dynamic graphics to an animation

Tags: graphics, animation

I'm making this demonstration that draws a parametric plot of the unit circle, while at the same time has two plots off to the side that draw the sine and cosine curves. I have this made up as an animation:

```
Animate[
    Row@{
        ParametricPlot[
            {{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {-Sin[t], Cos[t]}},
            {t, 0, n},
            PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}},
            ImageSize -> 300,
            AspectRatio -> 1,
            PlotStyle -> {
                {Blue, Thickness[0.025]},
                {Green, Thickness[0.0125]}
                },
            Prolog -> {Opacity[0.5], Circle[]},
            Epilog -> {
                {Dotted, Line[{{Cos[n], 0}, {Cos[n], Sin[n]}}]},
                {Dotted, Line[{{-Sin[n], 0}, {-Sin[n], Cos[n]}}]},
                {Opacity[0.5], Line[{{0, 0}, {-Sin[n], Cos[n]}}]},
                {Red, PointSize[0.025], Point[{-Sin[n], Cos[n]}]},
                {Opacity[0.5], Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[n], Sin[n]}}]},
                {Red, PointSize[0.025], Point[{Cos[n], Sin[n]}]}
                },
            PlotLabel -> "Point on the unit circle"
            ],
        Plot[
            Sin[x],
            {x, 0, n},
            PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1.5, 1.5}},
            ImageSize -> 300,
            AspectRatio -> 1,
            PlotStyle -> Red,
            Epilog -> {
                {Blue, Thickness[0.0125], Line[{{0, 0}, {n, 0}}]},
                {Dotted, Line[{{n, 0}, {n, Sin[n]}}]},
                {Red, PointSize[0.025], Point[{n, Sin[n]}]}
                },
            PlotLabel -> "Vertical position of point"
            ],
        Plot[
            Cos[x],
            {x, 0, n},
            PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1.5, 1.5}},
            ImageSize -> 300,
            AspectRatio -> 1,
            PlotStyle -> Red,
            Epilog -> {
                {Green, Thickness[0.0125], Line[{{0, 0}, {n, 0}}]},
                {Dotted, Line[{{n, 0}, {n, Cos[n]}}]},
                {Red, PointSize[0.025], Point[{n, Cos[n]}]}
            },
            PlotLabel -> "Horizontal position of point"
            ]
        },
    {n, .0001, 2 Pi},
    AnimationRunning -> False]
```

I want to be able to draw dotted lines between the corresponding red points on the circle and their periodic curves.

The only way I know to display several plots as one graphic is with `Show`, but that would use the same origin for all three plots. Is there a way to have two of the plots retain their coordinate axes, but have their images translated to the right of the first plot?

Comment: It is also possible to use a `GraphicsRow[{plot1, plot2, ... , plotN}]` or a `GraphicsGrid[{{plot1,plot2},{plot3,plot4}}]` to plot side by side or in a grid.

Comment: You can also use show on the graphics grid to draw annotations: `Show[ GraphicsGrid[{{ Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 2}]}}]
 , Graphics[{Red, Line[ImageScaled /@ {{0.0, 0.0}, {1, 1}}]}]
 ]`

Comment: ... or just `Row`: i.e. `Animate[Row@{ParametricPlot[...], Plot[...],...,...},...]`

Comment: The `Row@` suggestion seems to be the best option at the moment. The others make the animation very choppy. Now the only problem is figuring out how to properly place the line I want. I'm trying to make the endpoints of the line be the red points on the circle and sine curve, but `Show` is giving me an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *to draw dotted lines between the corresponding red points on the circle and their periodic curves*

First, create  graphics objects showing only the axes for the three plots, and translate and scale the second and third ones by appropriate amounts:

```
ax1 = FullGraphics[ParametricPlot[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {-Sin[t], Cos[t]}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, ImageSize -> 300, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> None, PlotLabel -> Style["Point on the unit circle", 15]]];

ax2 = FullGraphics[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
 ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> None, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["Vertical position of point", 15]]];

ax3 = FullGraphics[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
 ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> None, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["Horizontal position of point", 15]]];

axes = {ax1[[1]], Scale[Translate[ax2[[1]], {.5, 0}], {1/2, 1}], 
   Scale[Translate[ax3[[1]], {4, 0}], {1/2, 1}]};

Graphics[axes, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then combine all three plots in a single `ParametricPlot`, add the needed embellishments using `Epilog`, and use `Show` to overlay with the previously constructed axes:

```
Animate[Show[ParametricPlot[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {-Sin[t], Cos[t]}, 
   {3 t/2/Pi + 2, Sin[t]}, {3 t/2/Pi + 5.5, Cos[t]}}, {t, 0, n}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Blue, AbsoluteThickness[6]}, {Green, AbsoluteThickness[3]}, Red, Red}, 
   Prolog -> {Opacity[3], Circle[]}, Axes -> False, 
   Epilog -> {{Dotted, Line[{{Cos[n], 0}, {Cos[n], Sin[n]}}]}, 
     {Dotted, Line[{{-Sin[n], 0}, {-Sin[n], Cos[n]}}]}, 
     {Opacity[0.5], Line[{{0, 0}, {-Sin[n], Cos[n]}}]}, 
     {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{-Sin[n], Cos[n]}]}, 
     {Opacity[0.5], Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[n], Sin[n]}}]}, 
     {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{Cos[n], Sin[n]}]},
     {Cyan, Thin, Dashed, Arrowheads[Medium], 
       Arrow[{{Cos[n], Sin[n]}, {3 n/2/Pi + 2, Sin[n]}}]},
     {Purple, Thin, Dashed, Arrowheads[Medium], 
       Arrow[{{-Sin[n], Cos[n]}, {3 n/2/Pi + 5.5, Cos[n]}}]},
     {Blue, AbsoluteThickness[3], Line[{{2, 0}, {3 n/2/Pi + 2, 0}}]},
     {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{3 n/2/Pi + 2, Sin[n]}]},
     {Dotted, Line[{{3 n/2/Pi + 2, 0}, {3 n/2/Pi + 2, Sin[n]}}]}, 
     {Green, AbsoluteThickness[3], Line[{{5.5, 0}, {3 n/2/Pi + 5.5, 0}}]},
     {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{3 n/2/Pi + 5.5, Cos[n]}]},
     {Dotted, Line[{{3 n/2/Pi + 5.5, 0}, {3 n/2/Pi + 5.5, Cos[n]}}]}}], 
  Graphics[axes], PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> 900], {n, .0001, 2 Pi}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Note: All this works without error messages in Version 9.0.1.0 on Windows 8 (64 bit). For version 10, you can suppress the error messages using `Quiet@FullGraphics[...]` in the first code block above.

Comment: I must be doing something silly here. Did you assign a value to `n` before evaluating your axes definitions? Cause nothing seems to work on my end otherwise.

Comment: @MarcoB, thank you!!  I will fix it in a moment. Btw, any value for `n` would do to create the fake axes.

Comment: No problem. I realized that I could just give `n` any old value before evaluation, then `Animate` would take care of reassigning it anyway. Glad I wasn't going crazy there though ;-) And very cool solution! (+1)

Comment: Hmm, for whatever reason, I'm getting a slew of errors involving tick and axis specifications. I suspect this has to do with the use of `FullGraphics`, but perhaps you are using a newer/older version of Mathematica? I'm currently in 10.0. In any case, the animation itself works perfectly!

Comment: @user170231, I am using version 9.01.10 on Windows 8 (64-bit). I don't have Version 10; and the free Cloud version that I am using does not allow animations.  Changing `Animate` to `Manipulate` and suppressing the messages using `Quiet@FullGraphics[...]` seems to work. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun. This could made much more concise but I am time poor:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {1, 0} + {t, Sin[t]}, {Cos[t], 
    t}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 2 Pi + 1}, {-1.5, 2 Pi}}, 
  Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, Disk[{Cos[p], Sin[p]}, 0.1], 
    Disk[{p, Sin[p]} + {1, 0}, 0.1], Disk[{Cos[p], p}, 0.1], Black, 
    Line[{{Cos[p], Sin[p]}, {1, 0} + {p, Sin[p]}}], 
    Line[{{Cos[p], Sin[p]}, {Cos[p], p}}]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Darker[Green], Blue}, Frame -> True], {p, 0.01, 
  2 Pi}]
```

[image]