# Mapping one graph to another

Tags: graphics3d

Suppose I have:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Arrow[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}],
  Arrow[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}],
  Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{.5, .5, 0}]
  }, ViewPoint -> {2, 1, 1}]
```

And:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Arrow[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}],
  Arrow[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}],
  {Opacity[0.75], InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}]},
  Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{.5, .5, .5}]
  }, ViewPoint -> {2, 1, 1}]
```

Now, what would be the best way to lay the two graphs side-by-side (one row, two columns), then draw an curved arrow starting at the point in the graph on the left (the first above) and ending at the point in the graph on the right (the second above).

**Update Edit:** I tried:

```
gr1 = Graphics3D[{
   Arrow[{{-10, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, -10, 0}, {0, 10, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0, -10}, {0, 0, 10}}],
   Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{1, 0, 1}]
   }, ViewPoint -> {2, 1, 1}];
gr2 = Graphics3D[{
   {Opacity[0.6], InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 1}}]},
   Arrow[{{-10, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, -10, 0}, {0, 10, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0, -10}, {0, 0, 10}}],
   Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{1, 0, 3}]
   }, ViewPoint -> {2, 1, 1}];
```

Then I tried:

```
GraphicsRow[{gr1, gr2},
 Epilog -> {
   Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]
   }]
```

But only got this image:

[image]

How do we use the Epilog and Line command in this situation?

**Second Update Edit:** Looks like I've figure it out.

```
GraphicsRow[{gr1, gr2},
 Epilog -> {
   {Blue, Thick, Arrowheads[Medium], 
    Arrow[{{210, -152}, {580, -130}}]},
   Text[Style["T", 12, Blue, Bold, Background -> White], {395, -120}]
   }]
```

Which gives this image:

[image]

Comment: `GraphicsRow[]` takes an `Epilog` option; you might have to do some eyeballing, tho.

Comment: The best I can think of is some messy combination or `Row`, `Epilog`, `Arrow`, and A LOT of hand tweaking... Perhaps it may be more expedient to export the graphics and do further layout in an external program.

Comment: related q/a: [Adding dynamic graphics to an animation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83379/125)

Comment: @J.M. I gave your suggestion a try. Went to the documentation and looked at Graphics and searched the page for Epilog, but found no examples. Then I went to Epilog in the documentation and searched the page for Graphics, but found no examples. I've put my attempt in my original post. Can you show how to connect the two points with Epilog and Line. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: @J.M. I think I fixed your idea. I didn't realize where the origin was, where the positive and negative directions were, and the size. Thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant by "eyeballing". Good job figuring it out!

Comment: @kglr I did see[Adding dynamic graphics to an animation] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83379/125), which was a beautiful demonstration, but there were a couple of problems on Mathematica 10.4.1. The image titles did not show up and the second and third graphs started a little to the left of the origin. However,  I would really like to see your technique for my two images (no animation required) and the arrow and T label. The code might be much simpler giving me a higher chance of understanding the combination of the Translate and Scale command. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hardly think that this is the best way and it may not even fit with your data because the view point will be fixed.

However, if you remove the box and axes you can draw the two pictures and manually insert the x, y and z box lines.

Then use `Translate` to shift the figure with the infinite plane an arbitrary distance (I used -1 for x, 3 for y and 0 for z).

Now draw a line between the original point and the shifted point.

```
Graphics3D[
 {
  (* First figure *)
  {
   Arrow[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}],
   Red,
   PointSize[Large],
   Point[{.5, .5, 0}],
   Black,
   Thin,
   Line[{{1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 
      1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}}],
   Line[{{1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}}],
   Line[{{1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}}],
   Line[{{1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}],
   Line[{{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}}],
   Line[{{-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}}]
   },
  (* Second figure shifted *)
  Translate[{
    Arrow[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}],
    Arrow[{{0, -1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}],
    {
     Opacity[0.5],
     InfinitePlane[{0, 0, 0}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}]
     },
    Red,
    PointSize[Large],
    Point[{.5, .5, 0}],
    Black,
    Thin,
    Line[{{1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 
       1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}}],
    Line[{{1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}}],
    Line[{{1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}}],
    Line[{{1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}],
    Line[{{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}}],
    Line[{{-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}}]
    },
   {-1, 3, 0}
   ],
  (* Arrow between points *)
  {
   Green,
   Arrow[{{0.5, 0.5, 0}, {-0.5, 3.5, 0}}]
   }
  },
 ViewPoint -> {2, 1, 1},
 Axes -> None,
 Boxed -> False
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.