# How to connect 3 dots with 2 line segments when the dots come from different cells of GraphicsGrid?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I want

- to connect the 3 red dots
- to make the red dots depicted on the sinusoidal circular rather than elliptical.
- to make these 3 canvas are properly scaled such that joining lines are parallel to horizontal and vertical axes.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 GraphicsGrid[{
   {
    Graphics[{
      {Red, Disk[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 0.05]},
      {Dashed, Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}]},
      {Dashed, Gray, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}
      }, PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, Axes -> True, 
     AspectRatio -> 1],
    Show[
     Graphics[{
       {Red, Dashed, Line[{{t, 0}, {t, Sin[t]}}]},
       {Red, Dashed, Line[{{0, Sin[t]}, {t, Sin[t]}}]},
       {Red, Disk[{t, Sin[t]}, 0.09]}
       }],
     Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, t}]
     , PlotRange -> {{-0, 2 \[Pi]}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, Axes -> True, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"t", "Sin[t]"}]
    }, {
    Rotate[Show[
      Graphics[{
        {Red, Dashed, Line[{{t, 0}, {t, Cos[t]}}]},
        {Red, Dashed, Line[{{0, Cos[t]}, {t, Cos[t]}}]},
        {Red, Disk[{t, Cos[t]}, 0.09]}
        }],
      Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, t}]
      , PlotRange -> {{-0, 2 \[Pi]}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, Axes -> True, 
      AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {"t", "Cos[t]"}], -\[Pi]/2]
    }
   }],
 {t, 0.001, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Comment: something like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83420/125)?

Comment: for Q2: replace `{Red, Disk[{t, Sin[t]}, 0.09]}` with `{Red, AbsolutePointSize[7], Point[{t, Sin[t]}]}`; similarly for the other disk.

Comment: @kglr: Thank you!

Comment: "Is it impossible? If yes, I will delete this question shortly." That should not be a reason for deleting. Please keep it.

Comment: @Szabolcs: OK. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

Q2. To prevent disks from appearing as ellipses you can

1. Specify the radius as `Offset[r]` in absolute units. That is,

```
 {Red, Disk[{t, Cos[t]}, Offset[4]]}
```

and

```
 {Red, Disk[{t, Sin[t]}, Offset[4]]}
```

2. Use `Point` instead of `Disk`: e.g.,

```
 {Red, AbsolutePointSize[7], Point[{t, Sin[t]}]}
```

Q3: Use the same `ImageSize` in all three plots (adding invisible axes labels where missing to prevent different automatic resizing caused by different sized labels)

Q1: It may be possible to do it without abandoning `GraphicsGrid` ... but an alternative approach using a single plot with all the desired elements is possible:

Without the axes we can get the three plots in a single `ParametricPlot`:

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {2 + x, Sin[x]}, {Cos[x], -2 - x}}, 
   {x, 0, t},
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{t}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 2 + 2 Pi}, {-2 - 2 Pi, 3/2}}, 
   Axes -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 300, 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.03], 
   ImagePadding -> 20, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> False,
   Prolog -> {Thick, Dashed, Green, Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}], 
     EdgeForm[Dashed], FaceForm[Opacity[.2, Yellow]], 
      Polygon[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {2 + t, Sin[t]}, {Cos[t], -2 - t}}]}], 
 {{t, Pi/3}, 0.01, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

To add the three axes we need to construct graphics primitives that look like axes:

```
ClearAll[axisFunc]
axisFunc[tl1_: 5, tl2_: 5, to_: - 25][a_, b_, start_, end_, z_, 
   dir : (Horizontal | Vertical)] := 
  Module[{f = dir /. {Horizontal -> Identity, Vertical -> Reverse}, 
     p = dir /. {Horizontal -> 1, Vertical -> 2}}, 
  {Text[Style[#[[p]] If[a < b, 1, -1], 10], Offset[f@{0, to/p}, 
     MapAt[Rescale[#, {a, b}, {a + start, b + end}] &, #, {p}]], {0, 0}] & /@ 
     (If[tl1 > 0 && tl2 > 0, Rest@#, #] &@ Thread[f@{Subdivide[a, b, 3], z}]),
    Thin, Line[{f@{#, z}, f@{#2, z}}] & @@ {a + start, b + end}, 
    Line[{Offset[f@{0, -tl1}, #], Offset[f@{0, tl2}, #]}] & /@ 
     Thread[f@{Subdivide[a + start, b + end, 3], z}],
    Line[{Offset[f@{0, -tl1/2}, #], Offset[f@{0, tl2/2}, #]}] & /@ 
     Thread[f@{Complement[Subdivide[a + start, b + end, 9], 
         Subdivide[a + start, b + end, 3]], z}]}];
```

We use `axisFunc` with different parameters to construct the axes to be added to the `Prolog` option setting:

```
axes = {axisFunc[5, 5, -10][0, 2 Pi, 2, 2, 0, Horizontal], 
   axisFunc[10, 0, 10][-1, 1, 0, 0, -2, Horizontal], 
   axisFunc[][0, -2 Pi, -2, -2, 0, Vertical], 
   axisFunc[0, 10, -15][-1, 1, 0, 0, 2, Vertical]};

axeslabels = {Text[Style[TraditionalForm[Sin[θ]], 15, Black], {1.4, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}], 
   Text[Style[TraditionalForm[Cos[θ]], 15, Black], {0, -1.4}, {0, 0}], 
   Text[Style[TraditionalForm[θ], 15, Black], {2.3 + 2 Pi,  0}, {0, 0}], 
   Text[Style[TraditionalForm[θ], 15, Black], {0, -2.3 - 2 Pi}, {0, 0}]};

Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {2 + x, Sin[x]}, {Cos[x], -2 - x}}, 
  {x, 0, t}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{t}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 2 + 2 Pi}, {-2 - 2 Pi, 3/2}},
  Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.03], 
  ImagePadding -> 20, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  Prolog -> {axes, axeslabels, Dashed, Thick, Red,  
    Line[{{0, -2 - t}, {Cos[t], -2 - t}}], Line[{{2 + t, Sin[t]}, {2 + t, 0}}], 
    Green, Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}}], EdgeForm[Dashed], 
    FaceForm[Opacity[.2, Yellow]], 
    Polygon[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {2 + t, Sin[t]}, {Cos[t], -2 - t}}]}], 
 {{t, Pi/3}, 0.01, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Replace `Manipulate[stuff, {{t, Pi/3}, 0.01, 2 Pi}]` with

```
frames = Table[stuff, {t,  0.01, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/100}];
```

and `Export` frames as `GIF` file to get the animation at the top.

Comment: How about drawing across grid cells? Is it impossible?

Comment: @WellHarassedProgrammer, I will update if I can make the approach in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83420/125) work for this case.

Comment: Just seems much easier to dispense with GraphicsGrid and integrate the three plots into one plot that looks like three separate plots then can easily draw lines between the points.

Comment: @Dominic, that's what i did in the linked post. Getting the three axes right is a bit chore.

Comment: Ok I see that now. Sorry.

Comment: While I am waiting for the todo "lines across panels", could you tell me how to make the sinusoidal graphs have the same vertical scale as the radius of the rotating dot?

Comment: @WellHarassedProgrammer, Use the same image size in all three graphs. (also need to make adjustments for the different axes labels)